# Image slider not working (jquery)- Rails 3 project

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to set up an image slider using jquery bootstrap carousel.

It seems to be fine, except that the slider is not working. When I click the "next" arrow, the image does not change.

What am I doing wrong?

Best wishes,

Faisal

---

**JAVASCRIPT FILES**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
```

**SCRIPT THROUGH WHICH I AM CALLING BOOTSTRAP CAROUSEL**

```
<script>
$(function () {
//    $('.carousel').carousel({ interval: 2000 })

    $('#myCarousel').carousel()
        });
</script>
```

**VIEW**

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel">
 <!-- Carousel items -->
 <div class="carousel-inner">
   <div class="active item">
     …<img src="/assets/us1.jpg" style="height="200", width="200">
   </div>
   <div class="item">
     …<img src="/assets/us2.jpg" style="height="200", width="200">
   </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Carousel nav -->
  <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
  <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need you to reference the id of the carousel in the next/prev links like so:

Edit: Well you had a lot of typos, your image style is invalid. And usually I dont even have to call out the carousel in js, i just give them all unique ids.

I would take a closer look at the docs http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel">

<!-- Carousel items -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="active item">
    <img src="/assets/us1.jpg" height="200" width="200">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="/assets/us2.jpg" height="200" width="200">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Carousel nav -->
<a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
<a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>
```

Well copy paste this into your view... It should work out of the box, if you have jquery loaded.

```
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="assets/img/bootstrap-mdo-sfmoma-01.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h4>First Thumbnail label</h4>
          <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="assets/img/bootstrap-mdo-sfmoma-02.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h4>Second Thumbnail label</h4>
          <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="assets/img/bootstrap-mdo-sfmoma-03.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h4>Third Thumbnail label</h4>
          <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
  </div>
```

Comment: not sure whats going on... i updated my post, i hope it helps.

Comment: Well id try loading the default carousel off there docs. it that dosent work, then maybe your javascript files arent all there? I copied it in my post above.

Comment: I used your code, still not working. I also added my JS files above - am I missing anything there??

Comment: finally got it to work! the problem was that the JS files were not being loaded properly (i was loading from local; switched to google and its fine now).